# Fixed header shaking when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I use a `fixed` header, it's shaking when adding my `is-sticky`
CSS class. It's starting with `top:0;` for it's animation when scrolling down. I want it to stay fixed smoothly on top in a way that will not cause noticeable jitter. For Example: http://www.lazada.com.my/
Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/ovvfxg4w/).

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>0){
      if( ! ($('#scroller').hasClass('is-sticky'))) {
        $('#scroller')
        .addClass('is-sticky')
        .css('top',9)
        .animate({
          'top': 84
        },'1000');
      }



    } else {
      if($('#scroller').hasClass('is-sticky')) {
        $('#scroller')
        .removeClass('is-sticky')
        .css('top',9)
        .animate({
          'top':84
        },1000);

      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
    height:1000px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#scroller {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 84px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 30;
    background:#CCC;
    height:20px;
}
#scroller.is-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 9px;
    margin-top: -31px;
    height: 53px;
    z-index: 701;
    background: #CCC;
    opacity: .97;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 97);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="scroller">Some controls</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effect, from the website you linked, is actually quite easy to do.

Firstly, you want your header element to have `position: fixed`; there is no need to add this dynamically via javascript. It should have this property by default (as it shows in the website you linked).

What they are doing is hiding the top navigation which is *within* the `header` at a certain scroll point.

You can use jquery to do this very simply.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/esuyvr8s/)**

```js
var $el = $('header .two');
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $el.addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $el.removeClass('hide');
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

header .one {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: lime;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

header .one.hide {
    height: 0;
}

header .two {
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s;
    transition: transform .25s;
}

header .two.hide {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}

main {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="one">div</div>
    <div class="two">fixed</div>
</header>
<main>
    content
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My site is http://www.discountshop.com.bd/ here I want to hide upper part in header. when scroll.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check `.scrollTop` when is reached to 84. In addition, you don't need to use jquery `.animate` function, you can achieve that effect by css `transition`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovvfxg4w/2/)

Comment: @Lemon Kazi Does it fix your problem?

Comment: why are you soliciting responses from the OP in your answer, where he didn't comment? You are misusing the commenting system; someone with your rep level shouldn't be doing this...

Comment: @alirezasafian  yes your answer also correct. I removed animate function and applied transition.  +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fixed navbar and divide it into two parts vertically and when user scroll just hide the above part with `.slideUp()` animation and when user again scrolls on top show it with `.slideDown()` animation.
Here is the code :

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>0){
      //check if it is visisble
      if($('#nav-part-to-hide').is(':visible')) {
        //if yes then lets hide it
        $('#nav-part-to-hide').slideUp();           
      }
    } else {
      if(!$('#nav-part-to-hide').is(':visible')) {
        $('#nav-part-to-hide').slideDown();        
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body
{
  height:1000px;  
}
#sticky-navbar
{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
}
#nav-part-to-hide
{
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  background:#333;
  color:#fff;
}
#nav-part-stays
{
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  background:#bbb;
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="sticky-navbar">
    <div id="nav-part-to-hide">
      this conetent hides
    </div>
    <div id="nav-part-stays">
      this conetent stays on page
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying with your help.

Comment: I applied your code. http://www.discountshop.com.bd/ it's not animating . If I missed anything suggest.

Comment: @LemonKazi Well the code i provided works if you click on run code snippet so I don't think so there is problem with this code. The website has a long code and I don't have time to go through it all so really can't tell where you went wrong in that. But seeing the website behavior it seems as if  the div that contains search bar which has to be fixed on top when user scrolls down isn't really fixed at top when page is loaded, its fixed when you scroll, so put that search bar div in the fixed part of page.